# Why is Kaspersky antivirus blocking some requests to Google Drive?

Tags: windows-xp, google-drive, kaspersky

I'm  unable to access my Google Drive because, its just stuck at **Loading...** part. With the help of my brother, I found that Kaspersky Antivirus is blocking certain requests to Google Drive's servers.

Why is it doing like that? What is the solution?

Here is the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Judging by your tray icon, I'd say kaspersky is completely disabled, which is even more confusing.

Comment: What version of Kaspersky are you using exactly.  This would be better directed towards Kaspersky's support personal **if the license is valid.**

Comment: @Simkill: Yeah, I disabled Kaspersky's antivirus to check if that solves the problem. But I had no luck!

Comment: @Ramhound: I'm using Kaspersky 2012 Trial Version.

Comment: I had Kaspersky for a couple of years but quit using it out of frustration.

Comment: Sometimes even if you exit out of an anti-virus, it is still somewhat running in the background. A more definite method is to uninstall the software, or at least kill the process.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this might vary depending on what version you are using but:

Go to Settings... Under the Web-Antivirus settings you should be about to add trusted domains that it will not attempt to block (so in this case you want to allow the google.com domain). Also you may be able to simply disable the URL blocking portion (warning: only if you feel confident in your internet-"street"-smarts...) but I am not sure if this will cause Kaspersky to nag you or not.

As some commenters have pointed out, there also may be an issue with your anti-virus and windows notification as indicated by the icons in the taskbar, however I don't think it's likely that this is causing only certain files from google to be blocked.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem for about a month, and finally figured out that Kaspersky Parental Control was to blame.  No matter what domains I add to trusted sites, and no matter how "little" control I choose, I just can't get Google drive to load.  Neither can I get standard Gmail icons (arrows, the Google logo, icons like "trash" and "inbox" buttons) to show up.

I think the problem began after a Kaspersky update, but I can't be sure.  Gmail and Gdrive are not the only unrecognized sites.  For example, in trying to resolve the problem, I went to update my plugins one by one, and I couldn't even update Quicktime because the site was not trusted, and I didn't have an option to override it or add it as a trusted site!  I tried updating Quicktime three or four times before I gave up.

Unfortunately, this means that Kaspersky Parental Control is useless for me on Firefox.

However, IE will still load Google Drive, even if Kaspersky Parental Control is enabled.  Bummer that we now have to use IE instead of Firefox.  :(